# How to parse invariant json var names

Tags: json, go

Could anyone help me parse the following JSON? The tags do not contain "["/"]" brackets, but the left-hand variable names there are indefinite:

Example 1:

```
{
    "value": 569000000,
    "tags": {
        "importerId": "catchacar",
        "jvmProcess": "12367A"
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
{
    "value": 519,
    "tags": {
        "cluster": "cluster-29042",
        "valueName": "open-files"
    },
    "time": "2017-09-05T11:03:57.877Z"
}
```

etc

How can I define a struct which catches arbitrary left-hand values  ? I have found the following:

```
type JSONTag struct {
    ValueName string `json:"valueName"`   <--- what to write here ????
    Value     string `json:"value"`
}

type JSONMessage struct {
    Value float64   `json:"value"`
    Time  string    `json:"time"`
    Tags  []JSONTag `json:"tags"`
}

group := JSONMessage{
    Value: 123,
    Time:  "2017-09-01T14:26:33.773Z",
    Tags:  []JSONTag{JSONTag{"valName1", "val1"}},
}
```

But this produces and needs brackets. Example:

```
{
  "value": 123,
  "time": "2017-09-01T14:26:33.773Z",
  "tags": [
    {
      "valueName": "valName1",
      "value": "val1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
type JSONTag struct {
    ValueName string `json:"valueName"`
    Value     string `json:"value"`
}

type JSONMessage struct {
    Value float64           `json:"value"`
    Time  string            `json:"time"`
    Tags  map[string]string `json:"tags"`
}
... 

// usage: 
group := JSONMessage{
    Value: 123,
    Time:  "2017-09-01T14:26:33.773Z",
    Tags:  map[string]string{"foo": "aaa", "bar": "aaa"},
}
```

result:

```
{
  "value": 123,
  "time": "2017-09-01T14:26:33.773Z",
  "tags": {
    "bar": "aaa",
    "foo": "aaa"
  }
}
```